# More elegant way to read space-separated text values as integer and floats into an array?

Tags: ruby, code-formatting

I'm looking for a more elegant way to write the following code.  I'm trying to grab the first (2) values of each line, the first as an integer and the second as a float, and place them into an array.  Particularly line 3.

```
v = DATA.each_line.map do |line|
    t = line.strip.split(/\s+/).take(2)
    [t[0].to_i, t[1].to_f]
end.flatten

__END__
1       6000    ignore this
2       3000    94
4       1000    110?
100     500
200     250
400     100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into `scanf` (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/scanf/rdoc/Scanf.html).

It's like C's `sscanf`

Here's your script rewritten using `scanf`

```
require 'scanf'

DATA = <<EOM
1       6000    ignore this
2       3000    94
4       1000    110?
100     500
200     250
400     100
EOM

v = DATA.each_line.map { |line| line.strip.scanf("%d%f") }
puts v.inspect
```

and the output

```
[[1, 6000.0],
 [2, 3000.0],
 [4, 1000.0],
 [100, 500.0],
 [200, 250.0],
 [400, 100.0]]`
```

Does that do the trick?  I didn't try it but you may not even need the `strip`.

Comment: scanf() is exactly what I wanted, thanks!  I think it would have taken me a long time to find that one on my own.

Comment: As predicted, the `strip` was not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

What about :

`DATA.each_line.map{ |l| l.split(' ')[0..1] }`?

[EDIT] Ok, just tested your code... you want floats and ints and a 'flattened' array... so my answer becomes:

`DATA.each_line.map{ |l| [l.split(' ')[0].to_i, l.split(' ')[1].to_f] }.flatten`

Not that more elegant :/

Comment: Still nice to see another way to do it.

Comment: Ahah! Thanks!
@mr rogers is actually a pretty neat way to do it. I would never remembered using the old c scanf which does such a great job in this. 
Mine actually splits the string 2 times, which sucks a lot :/
Might have done it like ...map{ |l| c.l.split(' ') && [...]} or somthing, but still not as good.